# How to detect language with tag in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm designing the home page but there is some words that depend on the language of the actual home page.
I want to do something like this
{% if english %}
    Hello
{% elif french %}
    Bonjour
{% else %}
    Blabla
{% endif %}

Is there any template tag in django-cms that do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're thinking it wrong. Django supports translation, in Python code and in the templates.
The [Django Translation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) gives advice on how to do this.

You create a template with

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Hello" %}
```

"Hello" will be translated to bonjour once you set it up.

You will need to activate I18N in your project settings, then call

```
manage.py makemessages
```

to create a .po file for your project. Once you create the translations for the .po file, type something like

```
manage.py compilemessages
```

The actual way of doing things is a bit more difficult than this but is described properly in the docs.

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than I thought, but thanks for the awnser!, i'll will study the docs

Comment: Memo for later : you will also need to add the django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware to your settings middleware list, in order for django to detect the user language and serve the correct translations.